# Counting change dynamic programming: Does order of coin matter?

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion, dynamic-programming

This is the typical count change problem. I tried translating into a tabulation solution a couple of times, until I found one particular translation by another person strange.

```
def first_denomination(kinds):
    x=[50,20,10,5,1]#erroneous for the given DP code
    #x=[1,5,10,20,50] #works with DP
    return x[kinds-1]

def cc(amt,kinds): #either order of x gets cc(100,5)= 343
    if amt==0:
        return 1
    elif amt<0 or kinds==0:
        return 0
    else:
        return cc(amt,kinds-1)+cc(amt-first_denomination(kinds),kinds)

def dp_cc (amount , kinds_of_coins ): #must put coins in ascending order to get 343
    row = [1]*( kinds_of_coins )
    table = []
    for i in range ( amount +1):
        table . append (list(row))
    for j in range(kinds_of_coins):
        table[0][j]=1
    for i in range (1, amount +1):
        for j in range (1, kinds_of_coins ):
            d = first_denomination ( kinds_of_coins -j+1)
            if i >=d:
                table [i][j] = table [i][j-1] + table [i-d][j]
            else :
                table [i][j] = table [i][j-1]
    return table [ amount ][ kinds_of_coins -1]
```

The problem here is if I arrange x in descending order of coins, I get `dp_cc(100,5)=8061` which is strange, while only the ascending implementation gets `dp_cc(100,5)=343`. I have tried other implementations that works for both cases, but I'm not sure why this particular one doesn't work, since order shouldn't matter in these kind of questions. Can anyone enlighten me why?

Comment: Setting `x` in descending order counts some combinations multiple times. You can test for `amt = 3` and `x = [1, 2]` and `x = [2, 1]`. Not sure if it's fair to say that "the order should not matter"; the order of denominations is exploited here to get rid of duplicate combinations.

Comment: @YakymPirozhenko ur example still proves my point that there's a problem with the DP solution since it produces `4` for 1 case and `2` for the other case, whereas for the original recursion it produces `2` for both